# Android Password toggle want to set text instead of image

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I am using TextInputEditText as a password field. I want to use password toggle feature available with support library 24.2.0. *passwordToggleDrawable* allows me to set drawable to change based on toggle state. I want to show TextView instead of drawable to show toggle state i.e. I want show text '**SHOW**' to allow password to be visible and '**HIDE**' when user wants to hide password. I could see property '*passwordToggleContentDescription*' that takes text. I tried to set this property with as '@null', but it doesn't show text.

Below is code I am trying,

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
        app:passwordToggleDrawable="@null"
        app:passwordToggleContentDescription="Test1">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:maxLength="75"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

I am achieving this using framelayout. I am showing TextView on top of TextInputEditText

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="allstate.com.testfab.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
        app:passwordToggleDrawable="@null"
        app:passwordToggleContentDescription="Test1">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toggle_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:text="SHOW"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

I am handling onclicks on TextView as below,

```
textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toggle_button);
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                visible = !visible;
                if (visible) {
                    textView.setText("HIDE");
                    editText.setInputType(TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
                } else {
                    textView.setText("SHOW");
                    editText.setInputType(TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                }
                editText.setSelection(editable.toString().length());
            }
        });
```

Please let me know if you find better solution than this.

Comment: This sounds like it should be an edit, not an answer

Comment: Showing your current solution should be part of your question, so that we can better understand what you are doing and what went wrong. There's an `edit` button just underneath your question that you can use to change your post

Comment: When I asked my query, I didnt have below solution ready. That is something, I tried myself and found, it can solve my problem. I am aware of edit button.

Comment: Ok, I didn't realize that. You should probably make that more obvious in the future, since I thought you were simply adding on information

Comment: Please consider removing down vote. As I think, it is valid requirement someone will face in future and this post may help someone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145156/discussion-between-bapu-and-jeeter).