# TextInputLayout PasswordToggle - Handle click event

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

I have a `TextInputLayout` with `PasswordToggle` for one of my password `EditText` as given below,

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/password_input_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/text_input_height"
                        android:gravity="center"
                   app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/password_visibility"
                        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

                        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                            android:id="@+id/register_password_edittext"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"                              
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/appcompat_editText_height"
                            android:hint="@string/register_password"
                            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                            android:inputType="textPassword"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Now I also have `TextWatcher` implemented for this password `EditText` to handle validation like this,

```
 passwordEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                // Do validation here.
            }
        });
```

The problem is, when the user clicks on the **`eye-icon`** of the `TextInputLayout` my `TextChangeListener` gets triggered for no reason and validation failed block gets executed unnecessarily.

How do I avoid this? How do I handle `PasswordToggleIcon` click action?

Comment: this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44183004/android-password-toggle-want-to-set-text-instead-of-image

Comment: @Nilu - This is only a hack and not a proper solution. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 3):

```
        passwordEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        String textBeforeChange;

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            textBeforeChange = s.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (!textBeforeChange.equals(s.toString)) {
                // Do validation here.
            } 
        }
    });
```

If the text hasn't changed then no need to preform validation I suppose? Possibly I am missing the intent of your question. Cheers!

Comment: Nice idea. You'll want to do `s.toString()` in both places, and use the `equals()` method to compare `String`s, though; e.g., `!textBeforeChange.equals(s.toString())`. Also, the `else { return; }` is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks! I should pay closer attention when writing code in the comment section. I've been spoiled by Android Studio. Fixed the answer :)